# Understanding how to delete a record in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to delete a record in phoenix. Here is what I'm currently trying

```
def delete(conn, %{"id" => item_id}) do
  Repo.get!(Item, item_id) |> Repo.delete!

  conn
  |> put_flash(:info, "Item Deleted")
  |> redirect(to: items_path(conn, :index))
end
```

The problem is this tries rendering the show page and doesn't actually delete the repo record. Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this function is being called by the request you're making? The code looks good to me.

Comment: ^ Ditto. It sounds like you're making a `GET` request to the path that's shared by both `show` and `delete` actions. How are you requesting the page?

Comment: You guys are right. The path helper needed the method: :delete appended at the end. Thanks for the help